# erb sudoers iterate over hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

I try to generate sudoers file dynamically via puppet. Here i have hieradata like this:

```
---
  sudoparameters:
    cmnd_aliases:
      CMND_ALIAS_A:
        - /path/to/command_a *
        - /path/to/command_b *
      CMND_ALIAS_B:
        - /path/to/command_c
        - /path/to/command_d *
    runas_aliases:
      RUNAS_ALIAS_A:
        - runas_user_a, runas_user_b
      RUNAS_ALIAS_B:
        - runas_user_a, runas_user_c
    defaults:
      - user!authenticate
      - user!systlog
    commands:
      - user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/puppetd --test agent --server=*
      - user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/lsof -a *
      - user ALL=(RUNAS_ALIAS_A) NOPASSWD: CMND_ALIAS_A
```

And an erb template like this:

```
<% @sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'].each do |cmnd_alias| -%> 
Cmnd_Alias <%= cmnd_alias %> <%= cmnd_alias.map { |path| path.join(', ') } %>
<% end -%> 

<% @sudoparameters['runas_aliases'].each do |runas_alias| -%> 
Runas_Aliases <%= runas_alias %> <%= runas_alias.map { |path| path.join(', ') } %>
<% end -%> 

<% @sudoparameters['defaults'].each do |default| -%> 
Defaults:<%= default %>
<% end -%> 

<% @sudoparameters['commands'].each do |command| -%> 
<%= command %>
<% end -%>
```

My approach to iterate over the cmnd_aliases and runas_aliases doesn't work. How can i accomplish it to generate a comma seperatet list für Cmnd_Aliases and Runas_Aliases if these arrays exists in sudoparameter hash?

Cheers

Christian

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error? I can't tell from the paste if you've populated the `sudoparameters` variable in the manifest and if not, that may be an issue, or if something else is wrong.

Comment: There were errors in my *.map commands. But now it fails if an array in the hash isn't set.

`Detail: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue i wrapped the each blocks into:

```
<% if (@sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'] != nil) then -%>
  <% @sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'].each do |cmnd_alias| -%>
  Cmnd_Alias <%= cmnd_alias %> <%= cmnd_alias.map { |path| path.join(', ') } %>
  <% end -%>

<% end -%>
```

But for now the `cmnd_alias.map`doesn't work as expected. i get the following error.

```
Detail: undefined method `join' for "CMND_ALIAS_A":String
```

To solve that i save key and value to different vars and apply the join directly to the values.

```
<% if (@sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'] != nil) then -%> 
<% @sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'].each do |cmnd_alias_key, cmnd_alias_value| -%> 
Cmnd_Alias <%= cmnd_alias_key %> <%= cmnd_alias_value.join(', ') %>
<% end -%> 

<% end -%> 
<% if (@sudoparameters['runas_aliases'] != nil) then -%> 
<% @sudoparameters['runas_aliases'].each do |runas_alias_key, runas_alias_value| -%> 
Runas_Aliases <%= runas_alias_key %> <%= runas_alias_value.join(', ') %>
<% end -%> 

<% end -%> 
<% if (@sudoparameters['defaults'] != nil) then -%> 
<% @sudoparameters['defaults'].each do |default| -%> 
Defaults:<%= default %>
<% end -%> 

<% end -%> 
<% @sudoparameters['commands'].each do |command| -%> 
<%= command %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If some values in your Hash are nil, you can use this syntax :

```
<% (@sudoparameters['cmnd_aliases'] || {}).each do |cmnd_alias_key, cmnd_alias_values| -%> 
  Cmnd_Alias <%= cmnd_alias_key %> <%= cmnd_alias_values.join(', ') %>
<% end -%>
```

a || b syntax is helpful to avoid undefined method errors :

```
{:a => :b} || {}
#=> {:a => :b}

nil || {}
#=> {}
```

Finally, if cmnd_alias_value is an Array, it should be written as a plural : cmnd_alias_values. It's not a must, but it might make your code a bit easier to understand.

Comment: This is another approach to solve the nilClass error. Thanks for that.